# How does ExtJs form fields work

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

How do they create nice looking fields? Do they spit out html on the fly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".

You can [generate them dynamically](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/dynamic.html) or by [wiring up existing html elements](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Component.html#cfg-Ext.Component-applyTo).